What do people want with multimodal LLMs?
I don't get what kind of applications you can have with vision (not audio since it's barely here yet). And I'm talking about agents. Where would it be most useful??

Vision-based AI agents have a wide range of applications across various fields. In healthcare, they can assist in medical imaging for diagnosing diseases. In retail, they enhance customer experience through automated checkout and inventory management. In security, they are used for surveillance and threat detection. In autonomous vehicles, they enable navigation and obstacle detection. Vision AI also plays a role in manufacturing for quality control and defect detection, and in agriculture for monitoring crop health. These applications demonstrate the versatility and usefulness of vision-based AI agents in improving efficiency and accuracy across industries.


What do people want with multimodal LLMs?

E.g. image/video edits/question-answering, see https://github.com/BradyFU/Awesome-Multimodal-Large-Language-Models
